# ASP.NET MVC String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime

I searched on the internet for a while now, but every answer i found, didn't worked for me.

I am trying to convert a string to a datetime, but every time i try different things, i get the exeption: System.FormatException: 'String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

```
string temp = Request.QueryString["begintijd"];
DateTime test = DateTime.ParseExact(temp, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

The value of `temp` is: `05/22/2017 15:00:00`

I also tried "MM/dd/yyyy" but that also fails.

Comment: `MM/dd/yyyy  hh:mm:ss`

Comment: @gravity - Since his time is in 24h format, `hh` will not work as it's used for 12h. In this instance, `HH` is needed.

Comment: Thanks for the help @gravity! Just the change noted by @ben buurstra and its works :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, where temp = 05/22/2017 15:00:00, you need your 'format' in ParseExact to match that syntax.

So I would try this, `DateTime test = DateTime.ParseExact(temp, "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariateCulture);`